# grep in a data frame R

Tags: r

I want to search a specific column of a array of numbers for all results which are not NA. I filled as 12,12,12 dim array up with NA and then populated it. Now I want to search column 12 for values, so everything which is not NA. I am sure there is a possibility using grep() or somethign equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us how your data looks - it is pretty hard to understand the description...

Comment: its really just a 12 times 12 times 12 array of which I only want to investigate the 12th column in each 12 12 times 12 matrixes

Comment: As the answer shows, this really isn't a place for `grep` . `NA` is a pretty "special" thing in `R` and there are lots of tools for dealing with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on a 3x3x3 array. Select the third column for each array and then find the non `NA` elements using `is.na()`. To return the third column of each of the third dimensions of our array we use `m[,3,]`. This returns a 2-D array so we can use apply on this to select non-NA elements. Bad explanation but it's easy enough...

```
#  Reproducible data
set.seed(1234)
data <- sample( c( rep( NA , 7 ) , 1:20 ) )
m <- array( data , dim = c(3,3,3) )
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA    8   NA
#[2,]   10   13   NA
#[3,]    9   17    6
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3   16    4
#[2,]    5   12    7
#[3,]    2   20   NA
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA    1   19
#[2,]   18   14   NA
#[3,]   11   15   NA

#  Find non-NA elements in third column
apply( m[ , 3 , ] , 2 , function(x) x[! is.na(x) ] )
#[[1]]
#[1] 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 7

#[[3]]
#[1] 19
```

#### Update:

At request of the OP:

```
#  To find all values equal to 12 in the 2nd row
apply( m[ 2 , , ] , 2 , function(x) x[ x == 12 ] )
```

Comment: okay, is the is.na() specific to NA, or would it also be possible to find columns with a specific value in the ith row via a similar function?

Comment: @TimHeinert I really can't believe your default mode of operation is to ask if `is.na()` is specific to `NA` without looking up what the function does. Do you know that you can get the help to *any* currently loaded R function by typing `?` before it's name? `?is.na`. To answer point 2 - yes it is possible.

Comment: @TimHeinert updated to answer your second query. I hope that this will answer all remaining queries and that you will be able to accept this answer now by pressing the green check mark.